# All PDF applications mix the width and height of a PDF file

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdftk

I have [this PDF file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/test.pdf) created by scanning. When viewing it in any PDF viewer, the page's width is greater than the height.

But it seems like all the PDF applications I have tried mistake the width as the height and the height as the width for this PDF file (see below.)

Why?

Is the PDF file broken?

How can I "repair" the PDF file so that the PDF applications don't mix its width and height?

1. The following command shows the width is smaller than the height in  points:

   ```
   $ pdfinfo test.pdf 
   Creator:        Xerox WorkCentre 7830
   Producer:       Xerox WorkCentre 7830
   CreationDate:   Tue Dec 23 00:22:47 2014
   Tagged:         no
   Form:           none
   Pages:          1
   Encrypted:      no
   Page size:      612 x 1008 pts
   Page rot:       90
   File size:      81820 bytes
   Optimized:      no
   PDF version:    1.4
   ```
2. The following command shows the width is smaller than the height in pixels:

   ```
   $ pdfimages -list test.pdf 
   page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
      1     0 image     864  1400  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no         6  0
      1     1 mask     1236   895  -       1   1  jbig2  no         8  0
      1     2 mask      737   891  -       1   1  jbig2  no        10  0
      1     3 mask      247   381  -       1   1  jbig2  no        11  0
      1     4 mask       44   298  -       1   1  jbig2  no        12  0
      1     5 mask      429     9  -       1   1  jbig2  no        13  0
      1     6 mask       22   258  -       1   1  jbig2  no        14  0
      1     7 mask      130   142  -       1   1  jbig2  no        15  0
   ```
3. I am trying to crop away the left and right margins of the PDF file, using the script `pdfcrop.sh`
   [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42259/861) which seems based
   on `gs` and `pdftk`. My measurements of the left and right margins are
   116 pts and 20 pts.

   The usage of the script says:

   ```
     echo " -t \"<left> [<top> [<right> <bottom>]]\""
     echo "    trims outer page edges by the given amounts. Unit is bp. A single number"
     echo "    is used for all trims, two numbers \"<left> <top>\" are applied to the"
     echo "    right and bottom trims alike."
   ```

   but

   > pdfcrop.sh -t "116 0 20 0" test.pdf  trimmed.pdf

   will crop the top by 116 pts and the bottom by 20 pts, while the
   following does the correct thing by crop the left by 116 pts and the
   right by 20 pts.

   > pdfcrop.sh -t "0 116 0 20" test.pdf  trimmed.pdf

Answer (score 1):

### 0.

Here is a PNG made from your one page sample PDF file:

[image: test.png (converted from test.pdf)]

### 1.

> When viewing it in any PDF viewer, the page's width is greater than the height.

This is exactly as it's supposed to be.

### 2.

> [...] it seems like all the PDF applications I have tried mistake the width as the height and the height as the width for this PDF file.

As you said, it only *seems* like that.

### 3.

> Is the PDF file broken?

No, it isn't.

### 4.

You overlooked one information which your first command (`pdfinfo`) gave you:

```
Page rot:       90
```

It means that the PDF source code inside the PDF file tells the viewer to take this *"It's indeed higher than wide"*-page and display it with a 90 degree rotation.

Thus, *"viewing it in any PDF viewer, the page's width is greater than the height"*. As it is supposed to be. See my ***No. 1*** above. And my ***No. 2*** above.

### 5.

You can use `pdfimages` to extract all images, and then ImageMagick's `convert` to convert these which do come out as PNM or PBM to JPEG:

```
 pdfimages -j test.pdf test-

 for i in *.pbm ; do            \
    convert $i ${i/.pbm/.jpg} ; \
 done
```

This results in eight different images, the ones with numbering 0--7 in your `pdfimages -list` command from your question (**'2.'**).

Here are these images. All of them are scaled to 25% of their original size so not too much space is wasted. All of them are displayed in their "natural" orientation, as they are extracted by `pdfimages`. Here is the first one, number `0` in your list:

[image]

This image was extracted in its "natural" orientation. It is clearly higher than wide.

The following pairs of images are all scaled by 25%. They represent images of type `mask` in the list of your `pdfimages` output above:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

[image] [image] [image]

Your scanner (with its built-in software) is a more "intelligent" one. It does not simply make a single TIFF from the page and then embed that into a PDF shell, but it tries to optimize the different parts, using image *'masks'* (with alpha channels -- appearing as black colors in the JPEGs I created) for parts which contain text.

Luckily, your scanner software was not *"more"* intelligent when it applied its compression for the text, and it used JPEG2000 instead of JBIG2. So you did not fall for the infamous *"[Xerox scanning bug](http://www.dkriesel.com/en/start)"*.

Comment: Thanks. (1) what do you mean by "your scanner software was not "more" intelligent when it applied its compression for the text, and it used JPEG2000 instead of JBIG2. So you did not fall for the infamous Xerox scanning bug"? (2) how can I actually rotate a pdf file, so that "Page rot" is 0? (I tried `pdftk in.pdf cat 1-endW output out.pdf`, and the input and output pdf files' images have the same width by height size, but different "Page rot").

Comment: About (2), (1) "not the two blanks now!" or "note the two blanks now!"? (2) Why "Don't change the number of bytes!"? Even that means we have to do meaningless things? Can that be overcome? (2) My intention is to get a pdf file with `/Rotate  0` but still viewed the same as the original pdf file with `/Rotate 90`

Comment: @Tim: (1) Follow my links; read/watch whatever you find there. (2) Replace `/Rotate 90` in the PDF file wherever you find it by `/Rotate  0` (note the two blanks now!, Don't change the number of bytes!). -- Be aware that when you do so, the page content may be rotated off the page canvas, in toto or in parts... –

Comment: @Tim: **No. of bytes:** Two reasons. ***(1)*** A PDF has a kind of ToC, normally at its end. The keyword is `xref` (for *cross reference table*). The Xref table lists all PDF objects with their respective byte offsets. ***(2)*** Many objects contain *streams*. When that's the case, their `/Length` (keyword!) has to be noted. -- So, when changing number of bytes you may inadvertedly corrupt `xref` and/or `/Length` values.

Comment: @Tim: it is totally stupid and meaningless to try and intend *"to get a pdf file with `/Rotate  0` but still viewed the same as the original pdf file with `/Rotate 90`"*. -- Pardon my French!

Comment: No. It isn't stupid. When "Replace /Rotate 90 in the PDF file by /Rotate 0", the new pdf viewed in a pdf viewer will not be the same as the original pdf file. My goal is to get a pdf file viewed the same as in the original pdf file, but with `/Rotate 0` so that what I see as width is what other pdf aplications think as width.

Comment: @Tim: You'd have to 'transpose' the image data for that (`jpegtran` can do that), but it is "work for nothing".

Comment: do you mean first extract images from the pdf file? Is there a program which can rotate the images within a pdf file directly?

Comment: @Tim: Are you prepared to study PDF specifications (plus related file format specifications!) to achieve that goal? You need to set aside a few months, fulltime, for this. Then write your own tool! Tss...

Comment: @Tim: I'm ending this discussion in the comments section now. It is not meant for this...

Comment: Thanks. is there some concise document for study PDF specifications? I want to spend as least time as possible when I find the time to.

Comment: @Tim: The ISO 32000 PDF-1.7 spec has around 800 pages. But it references about 100 other standards (part of them 'industry' and proprietary standards): to name a few -- various fonts formats, XML, XMP, ICC, various compression schemes, encryption.... Combined you'd have to read more than 10.000 pages. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. About "your scanner software was not "more" intelligent when it applied its compression for the text, and it used JPEG2000 instead of JBIG2. So you did not fall for the infamous Xerox scanning bug", I tried to read the link in your last sentence, but the link doesn't explain what the "Xerox scanning bug" is, and I don't understand German in his slides. Why do you say it is lucky that Xerox used JPEG2000 instead of JBIG2? Isn't it that JBIG2 can compress more than JPEG2000?

Comment: @Tim: There are more links to follow from where the first one leads you. All the guy's blog posts are in two versions, one of which is English. JBIG2 in the Xerox scanning bug used a lossy version of its compression, which lead to replacing of individual glyphs (f.e. a `6` by an `8`).

Comment: JPEG2000 is also lossy. So same problem with JPEG2000?

Comment: No, not same problem with JPEG2000. JBIG2 uses a peculiar compression method, which is vulnerable to this bug, if its compression parameters are wrong. I gave you links -- why don't you look them up?